# what causes asp.net out of memory exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, out-of-memory, streamreader

I have a simple asp.net website which reads a large text file into memory and does some processing. Below is the code that raises OOM exception. After reading about 350k lines, I get this error. Each line has an average of 1k characters. Is there some memory limit with IIS or ASP.Net websites? My server still has plenty of physical memory left. Thanks.

```cs
List<string> geos = new List<string>();
using (StreamReader geoReader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("file.txt")))
{
    while (geoReader.EndOfStream == false)
    {
        try
        {
            geos.Add(geoReader.ReadLine());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Setup adplus to capture a memory dump on crash - syntax is something like: adplus -crash -iis  : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163833.aspx

Comment: There are indeed memory limits in .NET. Can you not break your data into chunks before processing it?

Comment: You could mess around with the memory limits, but that's a fragile approach, a bigger file, more processing more in memory objects will just use it up. The thing to look at is do you need all that data in memory before you can do anything with it. OOM is the net process ran out of memory, not your machine, in fact what it could n't even after a collect, is find a contiguous free block of memory

Comment: what do you do then with your list? If source file has large data why not use asynchronous operation to do an action for each line instead of storing it in a list?

Comment: Regardless of system memory, if this action is in response to a client request, that's a *very* costly method. 350 * 1000 * 1000 = 350mb. You're saying the error happens after 350,000 lines, but there are maybe even more lines? What happens if 10 people simultaneously run the same request? What if somebody gets sick of waiting and hits refresh 10 times? 3.5gig **gone**. As Alexei says, if you really *need* to use this much memory, run a 64bit architecture. Otherwise, consider a redesign.

Comment: Stop ignoring the exceptions!!! You're most likely having a problem long before the OOM.

Comment: @MitchWheat https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee310108.aspx not found ? which year and month for **MSDN Magazine** ?

Comment: Remove all not used dll files from bin folder. In my case it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your worker process is configured to be 32 bit (x86). In this case you will hit OOM at very least at about 2GB of allocated objects, but most likely much earlier.

If you really need to load more than let's say 1GB of object in memory consider running your code in 64bit process.

Note: above assuming you actually running out of memory, not something like trying to do 2GB+ allocation at once - which will throw OOM by default (the latest .Net allows bigger allocations as far as I remember).

Answer (score 1):

I did some searching on msdn and I found a few things that might help you out.

> There are a couple things to consider: First, the likelihood of experiencing an OutOfMemoryException begins to increase dramatically when "Process\Virtual Bytes" is within 600 MB of the virtual address space limit (generally 2 GB), and secondly, tests have shown that "Process\Virtual Bytes" is often larger than "Process\Private Bytes" by no more than 600 MB. This difference is due in part to the MEM_RESERVE regions maintained by the GC, allowing it to quickly commit more memory when needed. Taken together this implies that when "Process\Private Bytes" exceeds 800 MB, the likelihood of experiencing an OutOfMemoryException increases. In this example the machine has 4 GB of physical RAM, so you need to set the memory limit to 20% to avoid out-of-memory conditions. You might experiment with these numbers to maximize the usage of memory on a machine, but if you want to play it safe, the numbers in the example will work.
>      To summarize, set the memory limit to the smaller of 60% of physical RAM or 800 MB. Since v1.1 supports 3 GB virtual address space, if you add /3GB to boot.ini, you can safely use 1,800 MB instead of 800 MB as an upper bound

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972959

Another possible cause may be not having Service Pack 1 for .NET Framework 1.1 installed. I guess there is a higher likelihood of memory exceptions happening without the service pack installed.